# How do I store the shifted bit in a bitwise operation in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I was trying to make a simple function to check how many bits set to 1 were in an int.

What I achieved at first was

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bitsOne (int x){
    int r=0;
    while (x > 0){
        if (x % 2 == 1) r++;
        x = x/2;
    }
    return r;
}
```

I was trying to use the `>>` operator for this instead but I don't know how I can store the shifted number.

---

**Update**

Using Brick's suggestion I achieved what I wanted,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bitsOne (int x){
    int r=0;
    int bit;
    while (x > 0){
        bit = (x & 1);
        if (bit == 1) r++;
        x>>=1;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Do you care about negative numbers?

Comment: With `x >>= 1` although this will only work for positive numbers - better to use `unsigned int`.

Comment: @chux I do, would using brick's suggestion below work?

Comment: @C.Rib uSING `>>= 1` on a signed type with a negative value is implementation defined behavior - likely causing the `int` to never becoming 0.  I would not use Brick's approach with a signed variable.

Comment: @chux will doing `if ( x < 0 ) x *= -1;` first work? Edit: I guess not, forgot about the sign bit, my bad.

Comment: @C.Rib 1) say if `x== -1`, (typically 32-bits set), how would `if ( x < 0 ) x *= -1;` be used to result in 32?  2) If `x >= -INT_MAX`, then no undefined behavior.  If `INT_MIN < -INT_MAX`, (2's complement encoding)  then `if ( x < 0 ) x *= -1;`,  results in the dreaded undefined behavior when `x == INT_MIN`.  (e.g  `INT_MAX = 2147483647, INT_MIN = -2147483648`).  To be clear, what result to `bitsOne()` do you expect when `x == -1` and when `x == INT_MIN`? Until your are certain, just stick with `unsigned`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the bit in the last slot before you do the shift using a mask:

```
int bit = (x & 1);
```

Then do the shift on x.

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for! I'm not experienced in bitwise operations (hence my praticing), I know that for example `8 & 7` becomes `0000`, so does `7 & 1` become `0001` whick means that `x == 1`?

Answer (score 0):

`>>` is an operator like any other.  `x = x>>1;` will do it, which of course means `x>>=1` will do it.

**Update**

if you want to divide by 2 you should indeed shift by 1.

Don't make fun of me, I'm old.

Comment: So, alternate bits?

Comment: Bleagh. It's been a long week.

Comment: While I thought of this, this is not really what I intended to do, but I agree I should have explained myself better,

Comment: (accidentally clicked enter) while doing x>>1 is the same as doing x%2, I intended to do something like '1111001 becomes 0111100' and a variable stores the 1

Comment: @C.Rib `x>>1` is the same as doing `x%2` --> no.  Are you thinking of `/ 2`.  Even that differs from `x >> 1`.